# Proxy's Response to Asynchronous Close Events

Tags: http, proxy

Let's say you have an HTTP/1.1 proxy sitting between a client and a server. If connections are persistent, there is the possibility that the server will close the connection, but the client will send a request before being notified of the closure. What is the proxy's correct response to this? Does it send an HTTP error to the client or does it try to reconnect to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy should mimic the behaviour of the server, and close the connection - irrespective of whether there is a request in flight.

Automatically reconnecting can create unwanted side effects. The client would assume that it still has the same persistent connection and can, for example, skip authentication headers, cookies etc.

The other alternative - returning a 5xx error would also be wrong, since the client can also make incorrect assumptions about server state.

Mimicking server's behaviour is the safest and consistent option.